# How to delete duplicated pairs of nodes in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following DataFrame in Spark:

```
nodeFrom    nodeTo    value    date
1           2         11       2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z
1           2         12       2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z
1           2         11       2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z
4           2         34       2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z
4           2         34       2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z
5           3         11       2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z
```

I need to delete duplicated pairs of `nodeFrom` and `nodeTo`, while taking the earliest and latest `date` and the average of corresponding `value` values.

The expected output is the following one:

```
nodeFrom    nodeTo    value    date
1           2         11.5     [2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z,2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z]
4           2         34       [2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]
5           3         11       [2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `struct` function with `min` and `max`, only a single `groupBy` and `agg` step is necessary.

Assuming that this is your data:

```
val data = Seq(
  (1, 2, 11, "2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z"),
  (1, 2, 12, "2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z"),
  (1, 2, 11, "2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z"),
  (4, 2, 34, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z"),
  (4, 2, 34, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z"),
  (5, 3, 11, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z")
).toDF("nodeFrom", "nodeTo", "value", "date")

data.show()
```

You can get the average and the array with earliest/latest date as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
data
  .groupBy('nodeFrom, 'nodeTo).agg(
    min(struct('date, 'value)) as 'date1,
    max(struct('date, 'value)) as 'date2
  )
  .select(
    'nodeFrom, 'nodeTo, 
    ($"date1.value" + $"date2.value") / 2.0d as 'value, 
    array($"date1.date", $"date2.date") as 'date
  )
  .show(60, false)
```

This will give you almost what you want, with the minor difference every array of dates has size `2`:

```
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|nodeFrom|nodeTo|value|date                                                |
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|1       |2     |11.5 |[2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z, 2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z]|
|5       |3     |11.0 |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z, 2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]|
|4       |2     |34.0 |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z, 2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]|
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
```

If you really (really?) want to eliminate the duplicates from the array column, it seems that the easiest way is to use a custom `udf` for that:

```
val elimDuplicates = udf((_: collection.mutable.WrappedArray[String]).distinct)
data
  .groupBy('nodeFrom, 'nodeTo).agg(
    min(struct('date, 'value)) as 'date1,
    max(struct('date, 'value)) as 'date2
  )
  .select(
    'nodeFrom, 'nodeTo, 
    ($"date1.value" + $"date2.value") / 2.0d as 'value, 
    elimDuplicates(array($"date1.date", $"date2.date")) as 'date
  )
  .show(60, false)
```

This will produce:

```
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|nodeFrom|nodeTo|value|date                                                |
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
|1       |2     |11.5 |[2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z, 2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z]|
|5       |3     |11.0 |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]                          |
|4       |2     |34.0 |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]                          |
+--------+------+-----+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Brief explanation:

- `min(struct('date, 'value)) as date1` selects the earliest date together with the corresponding value
- Same with `max`
- The average is computed directly from these two tuples by summing and dividing by `2`
- The corresponding values are written to array column
- (optional) the array is de-duplicated

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a normal groupBy and then use a udf to make date Columns as desired like below:

```
val df = Seq(
  (1, 2, 11, "2016-10-12T12:10:00.000Z"),
  (1, 2, 12, "2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z"),
  (1, 2, 11, "2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z"),
  (4, 2, 34, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z"),
  (4, 2, 34, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z"),
  (5, 3, 11, "2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z")
).toDF("nodeFrom", "nodeTo", "value", "date")

def zipDates = udf((date1: String, date2: String) => {
    if (date1 == date2)
        Seq(date1)
    else
        Seq(date1, date2)
})

val dfT = df
    .groupBy('nodeFrom, 'nodeTo)
    .agg(avg('value) as "value", min('date) as "minDate", max('date) as "maxDate")
    .select('nodeFrom, 'nodeTo, 'value, zipDates('minDate, 'maxDate) as "date")

dfT.show(10, false)
// +--------+------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
// |nodeFrom|nodeTo|value             |date                                                |
// +--------+------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
// |1       |2     |11.333333333333334|[2016-10-12T12:09:00.000Z, 2016-10-12T12:11:00.000Z]|
// |5       |3     |11.0              |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]                          |
// |4       |2     |34.0              |[2016-10-12T14:00:00.000Z]                          |
// +--------+------+------------------+----------------------------------------------------+
```